# calling async fucntion in another file from main file

Tags: javascript, node.js

I wanted to call the async functiion hello() from the main file. The async function is in another file, functions.js

main file

```
var tasks = require('./functions');

hello().then(x => console.log(x));
```

functions.js

```
module.exports = {
async function hello() {
  return 'Hello Alligator!';
}
};
```

However always I get the error

```
async function hello() {
               ^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

Comment: you need to declare the property name.

Comment: Also your nodejs version should be higher than 7 or you should be using [babel](https://babeljs.io/)

Comment: Do `module.exports.hello`

Comment: And once you imported the functions.js, you have to access it on the value that `require` returns (`tasks.hello()`...)

Comment: @FZs... yeah I changed that and it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`module.exports` is an object and you should have `key:value` in object.

```
module.exports = {
  hello:async function(){
     return 'Hello Alligator!';
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is delete `function` from your code.

```
module.exports = {
  async hello() {
    return 'Hello Alligator!';
  }
};
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Method_definitions

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted, probably people are not familiar with the newer syntax in javascript.